# ajax with empty responsetext

Tags: ajax, responsetext

I have a simple ajax query working perfectly in other environment
(complete file named adv1.php):

remark: this is NOT cross-domain, as answered in many questions on this site!

```
<?PHP
if($_GET['uin']=='1') {
    sleep(10);
    echo 4711;
    exit;
}
?>
<html><head><title>ajax</title></head><body>
<script type='text/javascript'>
ajax=new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open('GET', 'adv1.php?uin=1', true);
ajax.send(null);
ajax.onreadystatechange=showres;
alert('request sent');

function showres() {
    if(ajax.readyState==4){
        alert('ajax says: ' + ajax.responseText + 'status:' + ajax.status);
    }
}
</script>
</body></html>
```

so when I run the code, I expect a waiting time of 10 secs (sleep...) and afterwards the responsetext 4711.
what I get instead is: "ajax says: status:0"
on the otherf hand, when i enter the url http://path/to/my/file/adv.php?uin=1
I get the correct answer.

i have copied and adapted this script from another script on my site. the other script works perfectly...

the script doesnt throw any console-error...

any help?
thx in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Move `ajax.onreadystatechange = showres;` before `ajax.send(null);`.

Here are some [examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: thanks, but this didnt help me.
I think, the function showres is to be excuted, cause I get the anwer
alert('ajax says: ' ...)
but I get the answer too early (sleep in my PHP is being ignored) and with empty responsetext and status 0 instead of 200...